# One wire AC power

Tags: power, ac

I would to connect a nodemcu board (powered by 3.3 V) to AC power behind the light switch, but I can use just one AC wire (the one that opens/closes the switch for light). Is it possible to do that using only one AC cable?

Thanks

Comment: you are misunderstanding the concept .... it is two wires .... one from each side of the switch ..... a small leakage current flows through the device when the switch is off ..... undesired side effect is that LED lights glow slightly when off

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no. To be able to power anything, current must flow in a circuit, and that requires a return path. So the minimum is two wires.

However, in a switch there are two wires. If the power consumption is low enough, and the load is leaky enough, it is possible to power some circuitry via that leak current. This is easier with incandescent bulbs, but even LED bulbs would provide enough leakage to power some circuitry.

The types of circuitry that are powered this way, tend to be completely isolated from any possibility of human contact. As generally it cannot afford the power losses introduced by proper isolation.